# Can CloudFront be used to create a one time use url?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I've looked through the documentation and did a bunch of searching. These are the things I know I can do with a signed url created with CloudFront:

- Set a time limit using a canned policy
- Monitor how many times the item was viewed

Can I also set a hit limit for my signed URL?

Comment: By one time use limit means what you want to do can you elaborate by example?

Comment: I need the url to only be useable once. If it's accessed a second time, the user should receive an HTTP status error.

Comment: Well you cannot make that URL for one time use using Signed URL as you can just adjust the URL expiry time there. Another way is you can restrict the URL based on an IP address so if that IP address tries to use that URL again he receives a Block response.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the info I was after.

Comment: Should I write down a answer?

Comment: Sure, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your use case you need a one time use URL using cloud front unfortunately using cloud front you can create signed URLs but you can tweak the expiry time of that URL not make it for one time use.

There is another way using cloud front to create a one time use url by implementing AWS Web Application Firewall where you can allow each IP address to access that URL just once by setting the WAF rules.

Comment: could you please explain how to implement this?
Condition? Rules?

Comment: Could you please?